# How to calculate the rise time?

Tags: current, cmos, rise-time, slew-rate

[image]

The figure shows a modification, from state A to state B, carried out on the cell at the output of circuit (X).
In both cases, the voltage at point A is the same. The transistors M1 and M2 keep the same dimensions.
How to define or calculate the rise time of the signal at point A?
How to explain or how to define the decrease in current through M2?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps RdsOn x Coss during commutation then current for cross conduction depends on Vgs/Vgs(th) * Vdd/ RdsOn.   So you know CD4xxx series with Ron starting at 300 Ohms operates from 18V down to 3V where Ron is 3K (rough est.) while 74HCxx is near 50 Ohms at 5V cannot run up to 12V due to shoot through current. And Vgs ratio is too high

Comment: Thank your for your response. 
The goal is to have a clear explanation in DC analysis or other. The voltage at point A is the same in both cases. The saturation voltages Vds of transistors M1 and M2 are also identical.

Comment: I can simulate this in Falstad or you can to create an accurate model, but basically you have one of the many std CMOS family inverters

Comment: I am designing a circuit where the cell represents the output of an amplifier

Comment: Sure,  Class D without shoot thru. Or a half bridge IC. It has been done before. Go find them.

Comment: @Yakeen If you intend to build an amplifier with a complementary MOS output, don't use that topology *as it is*, because that is the textbook variant, for exemplification, only. You will need to drive them separately and allow for zero driving. As it is, for 0 logic the `M1` conducts, for 1 logic `M2` conducts, so you can't switch off the output. Even so, for audio you'll see that there will always be a mismatch between an NMOS and a PMOS, so you'll probably end up with two NMOS, which will complicate things a bit.

Comment: I did all the simulations and it works well. I just want to know why the current is increasing through M2 (or M1).